# Chef each loop for each loop

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, erb

I have these arrays

```
services=["service1","service2","service3"]
ports=[11001,11002,11003]
```

For each element of services I need to assign the correspondent element of ports in an conf.erb file.
What I have until now is:

```
node['recipe']['services'].each do |serv|
  template "/etc/services/conf.d/service-#{serv}.conf" do
    source "service-#{serv}.conf.erb"
    owner 'serviceaccount'
    group 'serviceaccount'
    mode '0644'
    variables(
      :service => serv,
      :ports => node['services']['ports']
    )
  end
end
```

It sounds bad and the result is bad.

The result should be 3 conf files:

service-service1.conf:

service-service1

port 11001

service-service2.conf:

service-service2

port 11002

service-service3.conf:

service-service3

port 11003

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you,
Gabriel

Comment: Where do you define those arrays ? They does not look like attributes...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How I would tackle the problem:

In `attributes/default.rb`:

```
default['services']['service1']['port'] = 11001
default['services']['service2']['port'] = 11002
default['services']['service3']['port'] = 11003
```

**OR** (alternative syntax):

```
default['services'] = {
 "service1" => { "port" => 11001 },
 "service2" => { "port" => 11002 },
 "service3" => { "port" => 11003 }
}
```

In the `recipes/default.rb`:

```
node['services'].each do |serv,properties|
  template "/etc/services/conf.d/service-#{serv}.conf" do
    source "service-#{serv}.conf.erb"
    owner 'serviceaccount'
    group 'serviceaccount'
    mode '0644'
    variables(
      :service => serv,
      :ports => properties['port']
    )
  end
end
```

When iterating over a hash (what node attributes are based on) you can use the `|key,values|` syntax of ruby to get the key in the first variable and the value (which could be another hash) in the second variable.

Answer (score 2):

I would instead use a hash with the keys as your service names and values as your port numbers. Then you can increment through your hash with the key and the value.

Using your example code, something like:

```
services = { 'service1' => 11001, 'service2' => 11002, 'service3' => 11003 }
```

And then in your recipe:

```
node['recipe']['services'].each do |serv, port|
  template "/etc/services/conf.d/service-#{serv}.conf" do
    source "service-#{serv}.conf.erb"
    owner 'serviceaccount'
    group 'serviceaccount'
    mode '0644'
    variables(
      :service => serv,
      :ports => port
    )
  end
end
```

It's not very idiomatic chef though.